# Vertically positioning a table cell element works in Chrome, but not FF and IE OR vice versa. Alternate way to vertically align wrapped text?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, word-wrap, css-tables

I am having a cross-browser issue with the vertical alignment of a table-cell element. I can get it to look correct in Chrome, but not in FF or IE OR, I can get it to look correct in FF and IE, but not Chrome. See the mockup here: http://codepen.io/jphogan/pen/jaItL/

The wide, right text is a table-cell element. The reason I have it set up like this is so that, even if the text wraps the line, it will still be vertically centered with the colored background. You can double the amount of text on the codepen and see what I mean.

Here's my problem: if I set the .bpheader > .col to top:0; (like I believe I should), it looks correct on chrome (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/06U33.png), but is messed up in Firefox and Explorer (like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9OcW.png). If I set  .bpheader > .col to top:30%; (or a pixel number), it lines up in FF and IE like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF7TD.png, but looks like this in Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxgWz.png.

I've looked through dozens of threads here and I have tried everything I can think of with CSS (like: setting a height on the table element, moving positioning around, etc.) to get it aligned across all 3 browsers, but simply can't figure it out. Also, if anyone has any other ideas to keep the text vertically aligned even if the text wraps (must be compatible to IE8), I would LOVE to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can just create a specific CSS for firefox for the same class `@-moz-document url-prefix() { .font_example {font-size:1.075em;} } -`